# Expression Trees C# for calculating logic equivalence

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Recently I have programmed a recursion function for constructing an expression tree since this expression ((a|b)^c). But this is not the problem, the problem is when is time to evaluate it, since the final tree for the expression is given in the next form:

```
                         ^
                       /   \
                      |     c
                     / \
                    a   b
```

And  the problem raised when was time to evaluate it for applying the corresponding logic equivalence(in this case, distributive law). I tried using this algorithm for evaluating the tree as if it were an arithmetic expression tree:

```
evaluate(node) {
     if(node has children){
          left_val = evaluate(node->left);
          right_val = evaluate(node->right);

          // find operation symbol for node and use it as
          // val = left_val operation right_val

          return val;
     }
     else {
          return node_value;
     }
}
```

But it didn't succeed at all, because I couldn't get the values to be joined in a distributive law's form. As a result, I'd decided to look for a better approach and suddenly  came across with this approach of Expression Trees on C# but,  I'm not sure if its possible; and if it's possible, how can I use it just to get those  expression:

```
a^c 
b^c
```

I don't know how the Expression Tree works.

Comment: Although this question is interesting and even shows some basic research it is not good suited for Stack as it is simply to broad. However there are many tutorials out there that explain what expression-trees are and how they work.

Comment: By the way, `(a|b)^c` and `(a^c)|(b^c)` are not equivalent.

Comment: Thank for the advice!! I will start with some Expression Tree's tutorials! and well your'e right @harold but im just looking for converting the expression and then, split it in the middle  just to get the two expressions a^c 
b^c

Comment: @SalvadorRomo ok but `(a|b)^c` does not contain `a^b` or `b^c` as subexpressions. It's not that I want to complain about what you want, it's just that you're doing a pretty odd thing here. In any case you should not evaluate anything, just transform.

Comment: Ohhhh!! Right, I was so mistaken sorry. Yeah what I want to achieve is to separate this expression (a ^ (b|c)). I think that that expression is now equivalent, isn't?, I really sorry. So, I'd love to separate that expression and that's why I want to use Expression trees because with the other approach which uses the arithmetic approach is so confusing at the time when a value is returned.@harold

Comment: and also @harold ,Not only I want to create the capability of splitting that expression but also i want to be able to split expression like ((a|b) ^(c|d)) or ((a|b)^~(c^d) | c)  for converting every expression in only "and" format , that is why i need to use a better approach than the algorithm I've been using, the algorithm return just one value when a evaluations comes and since I'm applying equivalence, i need to be able to return two values and thinks really got messed up when i tried to apply it, as i result i'm here just to ask for a better approach using Expression Trees if its possible